# How to open .mx file Python

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica

How can I open .mx file in Python

I know this is some kind of Wolfram Mathematica file, but I need to open and parse it with python

How can I do this?

Comment: So far as I know that is a proprietary binary file format for which Wolfram do not publish a specification.  You will have to figure the file design out for yourself.  Start simple, with a file containing one or two simple Mathematica expressions, add complexity as your understanding grows.

Comment: documentation https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MX.html

Comment: note you can not even read these with a different version of mathematica.

Comment: If you have access to Mathematica you can import the file and export it in one of the many file-types that Mathematica can export. See the [Importing and Exporting](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImportingAndExporting.html) guide in the documentation.